# Does Lightroom take sensor size into account when applying lens correction profiles?

Tags: lens, lightroom, lightroom-4, lens-correction

I have a question about using the lightroom lens correction profiles for cameras other than full frame.

I have been using a Tamron 24-70 which is known for having slight vignetting (full frame only) and the normal optical skews at certain points in the zoom.

The reviewers have always said that the better part of that lens is right in the middle and frankly I can see that for myself.

I applied a lens profile to an image in LR that had no vignetting and it underexposed the edges around the photo so it leads me to think that it just applies the profile to the whole image regardless of crop factor.

My question is, could this have a detrimental effect by say warping the DX image into something even worse that what it was before, just because it expected deficiencies in other places (due to the full frame profile)?

Comment: If the profile for the full image circle were applied, it would *brighten* the edges to compensate for the expected vignetting. The fact that the edges are darker after correction indicate that the program expects the edges in the original image to be *brighter*, not *darker* than the rest of the image. This would seem to indicate it is at least attempting to take the crop factor into account.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Lightroom does take account of the sensor size. It has a series of correction profiles, each one designed for a combination of sensor and lens (and, in the case of zoom lenses, focal length).

Profiles for many common lens-sensor combinations are developed by Adobe and come with Lightroom. For uncommon lens-sensor combinations, the Adobe Lens Profile Downloader (http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=5492) gives access to profiles created by photographers and shared.

Comment: That doesn't explain how it differentiates between crop sensor and full frame. I can see that it has profiles, which I have already found but it is unclear whether it takes into account the sensor size as there are no camera details in the profile. I can also see with the Tamron that it tried to remove the vignette which is not an issue on a crop sensor which goes somewhat to suggest that it is based on full frame sensors.

Comment: @connersz I noticed the same in Lightroom that "I can see that it has profiles, which I have already found but it is unclear whether it takes into account the sensor size as there are no camera details in the profile".  Hence I asked the question http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/lens-correction-in-adobe-lightroom-cc